# BlackBerry date parsing and an hour's difference

Tags: date, blackberry, java-me

Due to the limitation of date parsing on BlackBerry I'm trying to roll my own parse/deparse methods, however I seem to be falling foul of an hour's difference somewhere, somehow.

I do this:

```
long nowLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
String nowString = DateParser.longToString(nowLong);
Date nowDateFromString = DateParser.stringToDate(nowString);
Date nowDateFromLong = DateParser.longToDate(nowLong);
```

When outputted in order it produces this in console:

```
[139.46] 1369132556831
[139.46] 21 May 2013 11:35:56 Europe/Dublin
[139.46] Tue May 21 12:35:56 Europe/Dublin 2013
[139.46] Tue May 21 11:35:56 Europe/Dublin 2013
```

My simulator's time is set to 11:35 so the third statement - `DateParser.stringToDate()` - seems to be failing somewhere.

Here is my implementation:

```
public static Date stringToDate(String date) {
    long l = HttpDateParser.parse(date);
    Date d = new Date(l);

    return d;
}
```

As my `nowString` includes the time zone I'd expect `HttpDateParser.parse()` to take this in to account but it seems not to be.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpDateParser.parse()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) is documented to handle "GMT" or a "TZD" which I assume to be a "time zone designator". I suspect this is expected to be the (horrible, ambiguous) abbreviation format - so for example, it might be worth trying to parse

```
21 May 2013 11:35:56 BST
```

and seeing what you get out. That would at least take you further in terms of diagnosing the behaviour of `HttpDateParser`. Keeping the time zone's TZDB ID is a better idea in my view, but you may well need to write your own parsing code. You still need to handle local time ambiguity though, where a particular local time occurs twice due to DST transitions.

It's not entirely clear what the input or expected output are in your case - how much control you have over the format. I'd try to use ISO-8601 as far as possible, with a time zone identifer as well if you need one. (If you're only trying to represent an instant in time, I'd use an ISO-8601 representation of the UTC instant, complete with a Z suffix to indicate UTC.)

Comment: Aha, thanks Jon. That certainly has pointed me in the right direction... the lower part of the examples on that page (god knows how I missed it first 10 times around) shows the example "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)" so I should perhaps look at how I calculate the devices GMT offset.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question; the intent of this is to store and retrieve a date in a database, then pass that date over a web API. I was suffering an issue with an hour being added when retrieving the date back from the DB which is what has led me down this path.

Comment: @Greg: Do you need to maintain the offset or time zone at all though? Or could you just store the UTC instant?

Comment: Jon: The date that is stored comes from what the user selects in a DatePicker, and prior to being sent over the API can be edited at any point so I need to achieve a few different things: 1. Allow the user to select a date, 2. Save that to a database, 3. Allow the user to edit that date (and obviously see the value it was saved as), and 4. Reformat that date prior to it being sent over the API. You may be right; subject to how the device handles UTC dates, this might work. Testing it now.

Comment: @Greg: Okay, so is it *just* a date? (No time involved?) (If you could use Joda Time a lot of this would be simpler, but I assume you can't.)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, that's my fault for not being clear - it is a date and time, not including seconds (eg. 21 May 2013 11:37). I'm able to use any external sources necessary, so if Joda Time is suitable then I can certainly have a look at it.

Comment: Joda Time relies on *modern* Java features, that are not available for the BlackBerry Java platform (which is basically Java 1.3 based J2ME).  No generics, many missing libraries you have access to in J2SE.  We try to steer people away from using the `java` tag on `blackberry` questions, because it always brings in solutions that aren't applicable to BlackBerry.  Retagging `java-me` ...

Comment: @Nate: Joda 2.0 uses generics, but perhaps an old version of Joda Time might work? In fact, I wouldn't be surprised to find someone had done a cut-down version just for Blackberry...

Comment: Certainly possible if it sticks to what was available in 1.3 / is generally targeted at *J2ME* devices.

Comment: Why not save the time in milliseconds in the database?